# How do I display the correct answer to the user's answer to the product of two random integers?

Tags: java, methods

I'm wondering how to display the correct answer right after where it says `"Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is "` in the `for` loop in the method `main()`. My problem is that the variable for the answer isn't declared until the `oneProblem()` method.

```
package multiplicationquiz;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiplicationQuiz {

    final static Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    final static Random rand = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    out.println("Welcome to the Multiplication Table Quiz\n");
    out.print("Enter your given name (no spaces): ");
    String name = cin.next();
    out.println("\nGreetings, " + name + ". I will ask you 10 problems.");
    out.println("Ready, set, go!");

    int qno;
    int numCorrect = 0, numProbs = 10;
    for (qno = 1; qno <= 10; qno++){
        if (oneProblem(qno) == true){
            out.println("Your answer is correct!");
            numCorrect ++;
        }
        else
            out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is ");               
    } // end for
    report(name, numProbs, numCorrect);
} // end main

static boolean oneProblem(int qno) {
    int number1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(10), number2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);        

    out.print("\nProblem " + qno + ": What is " + number1 + " times " 
              + number2 + "? ");        
    int answer = cin.nextInt();

    if (answer == number1 * number2)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
} // end oneProblem

static void report(String name, int numProbs, int numCorrect) {
    out.print("Test report for " + name + "\n\n");
    out.print("Problems attempted: " + numProbs + "\n");
    out.print("Correct answers: " + numCorrect + "\n");
    out.print("Incorrect answers: "  + (numProbs - numCorrect) + "\n");

    if (numCorrect == 10)
        out.print("Congratulations! You got a perfect score.");
    if (numCorrect < 10 && numCorrect >= 8)
        out.print("You did all right.");
    if (numCorrect < 8 && numCorrect >= 7)
        out.print("You pass, but you should try to do better.");
    if (numCorrect < 7)
        out.print("You really need to study harder.");

} // end report
static int getInt(String prompt) {
    out.print(prompt);
    return cin.nextInt();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why dont you do the prints in the method oneProblem itself. You can still return appropriate booleans after the prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `static` variable outside the `main` method as such :

```
public class Main {

final static Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
final static Random rand = new Random();
static int ans = 0;
```

Now, in the `oneProblem` method, add this:-

```
ans = number1 * number2; //Add this Line
if (answer == number1 * number2)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Now, the **correctAnswer** is stored in `ans`. Now you can simply print it out:

```
out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is " + ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way to return both the status (boolean) and the answer from your `oneProblem()` method.

One way of doing this is to use an abstract "problem" class  and inheritance for each kind of problem.

There are also some nice design patterns to do so.

A problem class could look like :

```
public class problem  {
    private string answer; // could be of an abstract parent class
    private boolean isTestPassed = false; // could be of an abstract parent class

    private (sometype) solution; // this one of concrete class

    public void askQuestion() { // could be defined at abstract parent class level
        // compute solution
        ...
        this.solution = // computed solution

        // ask question and get answer
        ...
        this.answer = // put user input in here

        this.isTestPassed = (this.answer.equals(this.solution));
    }
    public getAnsswer(); // could be defined at abstract parent class level
    public getSolution(); // could be defined at abstract parent class level
    public getIsTestPassed(); // could be defined at abstract parent class level
}
```

With this, you can create as many kind of problems you like, and you can instanciate as many.
You have convenient methods to get user answers and the solutions.

You are able to define a list, table or any kind of collection of problems to improve or extend your software.

Of course, as showed in others answers, you have quite an infinite amount of possible solutions to just print the user input. See @Shashwat's answer

Answer (score 0):

Given that it is a quiz, i'm asuming you are only trying to give 1 question at a time, if this is the case u can save the random variables on class scope

```
public class SomeClass{
private int ran1;
private int ran2;

public booleans somequiz(int in)
 ran1 = random.nextInt();
ran2 = random.nextInt();
}
```

this will mean that at any given time the current quiz randoms are accessible, untill the quiz function is being called again and they are overwritten by the new random int's, but make sure that the ints are at some point assigned before you use them or it will return a nullpointer

```
public class SomeClass{
private int a;
  public static main(String[] args){
   System.out.Print(a); // a was never set thus nullpointer
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the logs in the `oneProblem` method itself

```
static boolean oneProblem(int qno) {
    int number1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(10); 
    int number2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);        

    out.print("\nProblem " + qno + ": What is " + number1 + " times " 
              + number2 + "? ");        
    int answer = cin.nextInt();

    if (answer == number1 * number2) {
       out.println("Your answer is correct!");
       return true;
    }else {
        out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is " + (number1*number2));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

oneProblem can return a result Object instead of boolean.

```
class result {
  public result(boolean s, int n) { status = s; number = n; }
  public boolean status;
  public int number;
}

static result oneProblem(int qno) {
  int number1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(10), number2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);        

  out.print("\nProblem " + qno + ": What is " + number1 + " times " 
          + number2 + "? ");        
  int answer = cin.nextInt();

  if (answer == number1 * number2)
      return new result(true, number1 * number2);
  else 
      return new result(false, number1 * number2);
}
```

and when you want to check:

```
result res = oneProblem(qno);
if (res.status == true){
  out.println("Your answer is correct!");
  numCorrect ++;
}
else
  out.println("Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is " + res.number);
```